# Missing HTML comment tags

Tags: html

I've this WP installation that I'm currently modifying. And the craziest thing is that the HTML comments are not displayed anywhere in the source. That is if you right click on the page and "View Source". However if you are to open the page with a tool like this -> http://www.iwebtool.com/code_viewer?domain=w3lol.com you can clearly see that the comments are there. The website url is http://w3lol.com

The sad part is that there is no info anywhere on the matter and as a bonus I've no idea on how to determine if this is caused by the code itself, the Apache, WordPress or whatever...

(By the way, I've 5 other sites on this server, 4 of which are running WordPress and none of them has this problem. I'm also running an offline version of w3lol that does't show the problem either.)

Have anyone had an error like this? And do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: I see the HTML comments in source of that URL just fine, the first of them is not particularly polite. :)

Comment: I see a number of comments as well but also quite a few empty comments-- comments with nothing but spaces and probably a line break in them. Are those what you are talking about?

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: First of, I apologize for the first comment, I got a bit frustrated there :D The empty comments are fix for the inline-block element spacing, this is what was kind of important to me, because without it the page is all messed up. Anyway, I did test the website through Pingdom's tools and for my surprise it looked fine there, but I had my friend check it from all across town and she had the same error. Could this be in some way related to my ISP? Here's what I'm seeing http://i.imgur.com/YaZYN8n.png (PS. I tried debugging, but with no result).

Comment: It is hard to just guess at which point comments might be getting removed. Does it make difference if you open site in private tab in browser?

Comment: That looks like Chrome? I checked in Chrome on Windows 7-- the markup does not look like what you see. That markup looks like it has been "cleaned". My guess is that it is something on your end. Does you ISP offer some "increase your load speed" service? Stripping what _should be_ disposable data like comments is one good way to do that, which begs the question of "why are you using what should be disposable data in a way that forces the site layout to be dependent upon it?"

Comment: I tried opening it in a privet tab but it was the same, I tried restarting my computer and both my routers, but it even got worse, now more pages have their comments stripped. Now I'm almost curtain that it has something to do with my IPS and I'll be writing them in a minute. By the way @s_ha_dum, you're absolutely right, I'll be making some changes to fix the spacing issue in another way. Thank you all for your time and answers!

Comment: For the record, this ___does not___ strike me as being a case of your ISP doing something wrong. In fact, Google's `mod_pagespeed` will do the same thing with spurious data if I am not mistaken. I think the error here is in your choice of formatting hacks. :)

Comment: Just a note: It wasn't just caching and stripping HTML elements. It seems that my ISP's DNS was not refreshing and was caching even more stuff. As a temporary solution I changed my DNS to Google's public DNS as shown on this page https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using and everything seems fine now. But even though I called my IPS severel times they decline the error to be on their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my ISP's DNS was not refreshing and was caching some stuff. While waiting for them to fix it as a temporary solution I changed my DNS to Google's public DNS as shown on this page developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using and everything seems fine.

Comment: Thank you for telling us how you resolved this. Please accept your answer to close the question.